# Evaluation order of overloaded operator |?

Tags: c++, operators, undefined, standards-compliance, operator-precedence

5.15 Logical OR operator in the standard says the following:

> Unlike |, || guarantees left-to-right evaluation;

Does this mean somewhere I cannot locate in the standard, `|` is defined to evaluate right-to-left, or that it is implementation-defined? Does this vary when the operator is overloaded? I wrote a quick program to test this and both MSVC++ and GCC seem to evaluate *right-to-left*.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int foo = 7;

class Bar {
public:
    Bar& operator|(Bar& other) {
        return *this;
    }
    Bar& operator++() {
        foo += 2;
        return *this;
    }
    Bar& operator--() {
        foo *= 2;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Bar a;
    Bar b;
    Bar c = ++a | --b;
    cout << foo;
}
```

This outputs `16`.
If `++a` and `--b` are switched it outputs `19`.

I've also considered that I may be running into the multiple changes between sequence points rule (and thus undefined behavior), but I'm unsure how/if that applies with two separate instances as operands.

Comment: Note that even though `a` and `b` are different instances, they both refer to the same `foo`, thus you are indeed invoking undefined behavior because you write to the same variable several times without an intervening sequence point.

Comment: Calling each operator is a sequence point, so that would be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others said, it means that the order of the evaluation of the two sides is unspecified. To answer your other questions -

> I've also considered that I may be running into the multiple changes between sequence points rule (and thus undefined behavior)

No, your case does not modify `foo` in between two adjacent sequence points. Before entering a function and before leaving a function, there always is a sequence point, which means that both modifications of `foo` happen in between two different pairs of sequence points.

> Does this vary when the operator is overloaded?

All of clause 5 only talks about builtin operators. For user defined operator implementations, the rules don't apply. So also for `||`, for user defined operators the order is not specified. But notice that it is only for user defined operators; not when both operands are converted to bool and trigger the builtin operator:

```
struct A { 
  operator bool() const { return false; }
};

struct B {
  operator bool() const { return true; }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;
  a || b;

  shared_ptr<myclass> p = ...;
  if(p && p->dosomething()) ...;
}
```

This will always first execute `A::operator bool`, and then `B::operator bool`. And it will only call `p->dosomething()` if `p` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: The odd way in which `||` and `&&` are handled argue for almost never overloading them because almost all such cases I can think of will be very confusing. About the only case I could think of that wouldn't be is if you were using them for a completely foreign purpose like a C++ notation for a BNF grammar or something.

Answer (score 4):

Ignore that operator for now, and just take note of this:

```
(x + y) * (z + 1)
```

Here, both operands must be evaluated before the multiplication can take place (otherwise we wouldn't know what to multiply). In C++, the order in which this is done is *unspecified*: it could be `(x + y)` first, or `(z + 1)` first, whatever the compiler feels is better.†

The same is true for the operator `|`. However, operator `||` must *short-circuit*, and in order to do that, it must evaluate strictly left to right. (And if the left evaluation yields `true`, the evaluation ends without evaluating the right operand.) That's what the sentence means.

†Note that it may have no preference one way or another, and just evaluate in the order it's listed. This is why you get the output you do, though you cannot rely on it at the language level.

Comment: Shouldn't it end the evaluation if the left operand yields true?

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean somewhere I cannot locate in the standard, | is defined to evaluate right-to-left, or that it is implementation-defined?

Pedantically speaking the order of evaluation of arguments of  `|` operator is unspecified. So that means the operands can be evaluated in either order.

However the order of evaluation of operands of logical operators (i.e `&&`, `||` etc) and comma operator is specified i.e from left to right.

Comment: Except, I do not think that applies if `&&` or `||` are overloaded.